# How to make widget test wait until Bloc has updated the state?

Tags: testing, flutter, bloc

I have a `EmailScreen` (stateful widget) that has a text input, and a button. The button is only enabled when a valid email is input.

I'm using Bloc, and my screen has `InitialEmailState` and `ValidEmailInputState`, and it works fine when I run the app.

In my widget test, the second expectation is failing before bloc has a chance to update the state:

```dart
  testWidgets('when valid email is input, button is enabled', (tester) async {
    const validEmail = 'email@provider.com';

    emailBloc.listen((event) {
      print('NEW EVENT: ' + event.toString());
    });

    await bootUpWidget(tester, emailScreen);

    final BottomButton button = tester.widget(
        find.widgetWithText(BottomButton, 'CONTINUE'));

    expect(button.enabled, isFalse);

    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextInputScreen), validEmail);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(button.enabled, isTrue);
  });
```

And here's the output I'm getting:

```
NEW EVENT: InitialEmailState
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: true
  Actual: <false>

...

The test description was:
  when valid email is input, button is enabled
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: when valid email is input, button is enabled

NEW EVENT: InputValidEmailState
✖ when valid email is input, button is enabled
Exited (1)
```

As you can see, it prints the initial state, fails the second expectation, and then prints the expected state.

Thanks in advance :)

**== UPDATE ==**

We managed to get this to work by adding `LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding();` to the start of our main. But it doesn't feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

Encountered the same issue with BLoC driven UI widgets, I found the solution is pretty simple: use `expectLater()` rather than `expect()` to wait for BLoC state update:

```dart
testWidgets('test widgets driven by BLoC', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(yourWidget);

  await tester.tap(loginButton); // Do something like tapping a button, entering text
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  await expectLater(findSomething, findsOneWidget); // IMPRTANT: use `expectLater` to wait for BLoC state update
  expect(findSomethingElse, findsOneWidget); // Subsequently you can use normal version `expect` until next `tester.pumpAndSettle()`
}
```

I put breakpoints into the BLoC to figure out what's the problem, it turns out that without using `expectLater`, the normal `expect` is being evaluated before the BLoC stream emits a new state. That is to say BLoC does emit a new state, but at that time the test case already runs to the end.

By using `expectLater`, it is being evaluated after the new state is emitted.